# android - parsing JSONArray that doesn't have explicit JSONObject

Tags: android, arrays, json, parsing

I know how to parse JSON that looks like [{...},{...},{...}]. But here is my example and something is a bit different:

```
[{"type":"sometype","presentations":["/files/presentation/presentation.pdf"],"description":"somedescription"},{"type":"sometype","presentations":["/files/presentation/presentation2.pdf"],"description":"somedescription"}]
```

How to parse data from "presentations" here? I'm getting it as JSONArray, but can't get a value (using .toString() with that array returns that value, but with "\" before "/" (I mean "/files/presentation..."), so I can't add it to url to display pdf. And I don't know how to get JSONObject from that array (if it exists, of course).

Comment: What you have tried yet can you post the code where you are doing parsing.

Comment: I can copypaste it right as it is, but later. Saying in natural language, I converted this string into JSONArray, then extracted JSONObject from this array by its number, then did .getString("presentations"), then converted it to JSONArray ('cause it should be array, right?). Further I made several things: 1)I thought it was an implicit JSONObject so I tried to get jSONObject by number 0 and then converted it to string but as I remember I even couldn't get Object. 2) I tried to convert to string JSONArray itself hoping to substring it without [], and consequences ("\/") are described above

Comment: First of all you can check the json which is coming as response to you from server there are several sites [First link](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) [Second link](http://json.parser.online.fr/). You can check here whether your json is correct or not and you can clearly see which is normal field or an object or an array.

Comment: @JustinMcGuire did my answer work for you?

Comment: @AlexandreG Done. I wanted to upvote it but my rating doesn't let me so far. The only thing - please change to getJSONObject(1) in "string2", maybe some beginners won't get at once, why string and string2 are the same :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String jsonString = "[{\"type\":\"sometype\",\"presentations\":[\"/files/presentation/presentation.pdf\"],\"description\":\"somedescription\"},{\"type\":\"sometype\",\"presentations\":[\"/files/presentation/presentation2.pdf\"],\"description\":\"somedescription\"}]";

try {
    JSONArray jaArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);
    JSONObject firstElement = jaArray.getJSONObject(0);
    JSONArray jaPresentations = firstElement.getJSONArray("presentations");
    String string = jaPresentations.getString(0);

    //or chain it together like so:
    String string2 = jaArray.getJSONObject(1).getJSONArray("presentations").getString(0);

    Log.v("TAG", string);
    Log.v("TAG", string2);
```

Output:

```
V/TAG﹕ /files/presentation/presentation.pdf
V/TAG﹕ /files/presentation/presentation2.pdf
```